# Android - Tabbar - Title next to icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I have the following code and you can see I only have tow options:

- `TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER`
- `TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL`

And none of both works like i want to achieve on the image.

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new 
    SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_whatshot_white_24dp).setText("Tendencias");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_cake_white_24dp).setText("Cercanos");;
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1e564f"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
```

This is what i want.
[image]

This is what i get(please ignore the fact of title and icons are diferent)
[image]

Comment: check this [6. Custom Tab View with Icon & Text](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: Those gravity values don't affect the tabs' individual content, but how the tabs are displayed altogether in their strip. You'll need to use a custom layout for the tabs, since, IIRC, the default is strictly icon-above-text.